# How load not OS Application with at91bootstrap bootloader on ATMEL ARM 9 Procesoor

Tags: arm, bootloader, atmel

I want to Load my application with AT91BootStrap bootloader  instead of U-boot and OS.
My Chip is Atmel ARM 9 processor.( AT91SAMX25)
How i Can do it, what is the constrains of application and compile.
Is there any sample for it.

Comment: should all be described in the manuals.  both how to get into that mode, what interface to use and what protocol.  The protocol will tell you if you can only use it to program application flash or if you can use it to run things from ram, and from that you use the manuals to determine what the address for application flash is (if other than 0x00000000) or ram and from that how to tell the linker what to do.

Comment: yes appears to be a classic samba monitor, fairly simple serial interface or you can use one of many tools that supports it from Atmel/Microchip or other third party (and/or open source) places.  Or roll your own in an afternoon.  I dont remember off hand if you have to program the flash or you can also run from ram if desired.  Eventually you want to be running from flash.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can load and launch bare-metal code from U-boot, which is likely to be a fair bit less hassle than going _all_ the way back to basics. After all, an OS is nothing more than a big bare-metal application anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use proper spelling and grammar, it really does make your question downvoted less. It also takes extra time for potential helpers to process, reducing their attention span.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC - While you're busy telling the OP how to deal with spelling and grammar, you should consider your own edits (which I just rolled back), as you changed the title to "spelling, grammar." Further, your additional edits didn't add any noticeable improvement, aside from some capitalization changes.

Comment: @DavidMakogon that was an accident; I meant to put it in the edit summary.

Comment: @DavidMakogon other than the mistake I made, it improves the post